# Сделать dropdown в yii\grid\SerialColumn Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема, дело в том что хочу чтобы в `yii\grid\SerialColumn` был не `input` с типом `text`, а dropdown, чтобы можно было выбрать только конкретные значения.
Т.е. сама ячейка представляет собой ячейку статусов, и вручную имя статуса вводить очень неудобно, поэтому лучше предоставлять dropdownlist.

Как это можно реализовать?

Добавлю визуальную составляющую, чтобы было понятнее:

С текстового `input`: 
[image: как есть]

В `select`:

[image: как нужно]

Comment: просто передайте массив в виде `['ключ' => 'значение', ...]` в параметр `filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `GridView` в `columns` нужно сделать кастомный column с настройками, а в него передать данные в `filter`. Пример:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'status',
    'format' => 'html',
    'label' => 'Статус',
    'value' => function($model) {
        switch ($model->status){
            case 0: {
                $label = "Новая заявка";
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                $label = "Проверяется оплата";
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                $label = "Заявка в процессе";
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                $label = "Заявка выполнена";
                break;
            }
            default: {
                $label = "Статус неопределен";
            }
        }

        return $label;
    },

    'filter' =>  Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'status', [
        0 => 'Новая заявка',
        1 => 'Проверяется оплата',
        2 => 'Заявка в процессе',
        3 => 'Заявка выполнена',
        '' => 'Все'
    ]),
],
```

**Результат:**

[image: Результат исполнения]